# Empty/Zero Result with Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus within a Function or Expression

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-server

I'am not able to get any results of the Exchange Management CmdLet (OnPremises) `Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus` within a Function or Expression.

```
function Get-DAGDatabaseCopys ($Identity) {
   # Neither this line:
   #[Int]$DBCopys = Invoke-Command { @(Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity $Identity).count }
   # Or this line works:
   $DBCopys = @(Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity $Identity).count
   return $DBCopys
}
```

Usage:

```
Get-DAGDatabaseCopys -Identity "DatabaseName"
```

Expression Example:

```
$strMasterType = "DatabaseAvailabilityGroup"
$expDatabaseSpaceGB   = @{Expression={if(($_.MasterType -eq $strMasterType) -and ($IncludeDagCopys)){
    start-sleep 1 
    $DBCopys = @(Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus -Identity $_).count
    return [math]::Round((Value-ToGB -Value $_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace),2) * $DBCopys
};Label="DatabaseWhiteSpaceSizeGB"}
```

Usage:

```
$MailboxDBStatus      = Get-MailboxDatabase -Status | select ServerName, Name, MasterType, $expDatabaseSpaceGB
```

The Returnvalue of the function or expression will always be `empty` or `0` (if DataType is Int). There is no data in the `$DBCopys` Object within the function/expression, even if i try to receive the full object (not just the count).

The Same CmdLet direct in the Script Root or on the Powershell Console work's as expected.

Is this a general behaviour of this cmdlet or am I doing something wrong here?

Thx.

Comment: Hi, it's been a while, has your problem been resolved? If the below info is helpful to you, you could mark the best answer. Have a nice day:-)

Comment: Is there any update?

Comment: I solved it by avoiding the inline expressions. Thanks for your help and sorry for the long delay. That was for personal reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmdlets are working as expected within a function or in the script root. The problem only occurs within inline powershell expressions. So i solved it by avoiding the inline expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge and test, the **`AvailableNewMailboxSpace`** parameter is only used for  the **`Get-MailboxDatabase`** cmdlet rather than **`Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus`** cmdlet:
[image]

Do you want to get the value of the `AvailableNewMailboxSpace` parameter or the free space of your disk(**DiskFreeSpace**)?
[image]

If it's the former, I think you need replace the **`Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus`** cmdlet with the **`Get-MailboxDatabase -Status`** cmdlet. If it's the latter,  replace the **`AvailableNewMailboxSpace`** cmdlet with the **`DiskFreeSpace`** cmdlet.

Besides, the cmdlet **`Value-ToGB -Value`** seems not be supported by PowerShell, I think you could try using the following command:

```
return [math]::Round(($_.AvailableNewMailboxSpace)/1GB,2) * $DBCopys
```

Comment: The goal was to get the number of MBX Copys and multiply it with the available Database Copy within an expression for billing related calculations. 

The cmdlets are working as expected within a function or in the script root. The problem only occurs within inline powershell expressions. 

So i solved it by avoiding the inline expressions. 

'Value-ToGB -Value' is a custom function which does exactly the same as your math code example. 

Thanks for your help and sorry for the long delay. That was for personal reasons.